# AngularFire2 avoid null value after ObjectObservable remove

Tags: json, angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have a HTML list build with `ngFor` from [AngularFire2 ObjectObservable](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/2-retrieving-data-as-objects.md).

Once a object(not last) is deleted from the Database, `null` appears in his position(index) and the HTML list tries to update but an error is thrown from the ngFor loop.

JSON from AngularFire2 DB:

```
let tasksList = {
  "name": "Task list",
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "Task 1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Test 2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Test 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

HTML:

```
    <ul *ngFor="let theTask of tasksList.items">
      <li>{{theTask.name}}</li>
    </ul>
```

**After task 1 has been removed**, the JSON looks like this:

```
let tasksList = {
  "name": "Task list",
  "items": [
    null,
    {
      "name": "Test 2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Test 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I think that the simplest solution would be to stop the `null` value from replacing the `deleted object`.
But is that possible?

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain how you have received a JSON structure that includes an array? When array data is written to Firebase, it is converted to an object with keys derived from the array indices. Your question might be answerable if it included the code that reads and deletes data, but in its current form I cannot see how anyone could answer this.

Comment: What error is thrown?

Comment: Thanks for your involvement, I'll try to provide the details today.

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't been able to post more details yesterday.

Today, a solution(probably temporary) came in my mind.(my comment at the winning answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use angular 2's *pipe* (angular 1's *filter*) in order to filter all empty items:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'removeNull', pure: false})
export class RemoveNullPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[]): any {
    return items.filter(item => item);
  }
}
```

then use it in HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let theTask of tasksList.items | removeNull">{{ theTask.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

I moved `*ngFor` from `<ul>` to `<li>` element, it seems better to repeat `<li>`s within `<ul>` and not repeat `ul`s

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/IQq45kaJqqWRZOqhZdoe?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much for this wonderful example.
This solves my  problem on the VIEW.

To solve the problem with 'null' on the Firebase2 DB, I'll 'get' all the 'items' => update them on my end => 'set' them on the DB(without an element)